# Parametric Equation of sine wave helically wrapped around a cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, parametric

I want a parametric equation of a sine wave at a small ramp angle wrapped around a cylindrical body (3D).

The parametric equation below gets me close to what I'm looking for, but not quite since the sine wave itself is not rotated (peaks still in line with the longitudinal direction of the cylindrical body).

$$x(t)=\sin(t)$$
$$y(t)=\cos(t)$$
$$z(t)=0.5t+\sin(4.5t)$$

In 2D, the following parametric equation will give me a rotated sine wave. How can I convert this to 3D around the cylinder following a helical pattern? The theta variable is the angle from the x-axis that the sine wave is rotated.

$$x(t)=t\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\sin(t)$$
$$y(t)=t\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\sin(t)$$

I appreciate any help you may be able to offer.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the graph of sine around a line that turns into a curve around a helix when the plane is rolled into a cylinder?

Comment: I am looking for the parametric equation that will give me a sine wave that follows the surface of a cylinder along a helical path. I'm not looking for a toroid in a helical pattern, if that is what you are asking. The first parametric equation gives me a sine wave in which all the peaks are aligned in the longitudinal direction. what I am looking for is, if you were to graph a sine wave in 2D on a piece of paper, rotate the paper slightly, and then roll it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, where $t$ represents the main parameter, $\theta$ is the tilting angle as the sine wave wraps around the cylinder, $k$ is the frequency of the sine wave, and $a$ is the amplitude:

$$\begin{align*} x(t) &= \cos (t \cos \theta - a \sin \theta \sin (k t)) \\ y(t) &= \sin (t \cos \theta - a \sin \theta \sin (k t)), \\ z(t) &= t \sin \theta +  a \cos \theta \sin (k t). \end{align*}$$

Fancy animated picture! [image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. Can you explain how you got this? Was this just application of a combination of rotational matrices?

Comment: If you look at the form of the equations, you can see that all I did was take your existing results and modified them appropriately.  Your 2D equations, when mapped onto a 3D cylinder, change from $(x,y)$ to $({\rm angle},z)$, which means that if you wrap the 2D $x(t)$ in $\cos$ and $\sin$, and take the 2D $y(t)$ equation as your 3D $z(t)$, you will get the desired result.  The rest is just a matter of generalizing the 2D formula in such a way as to permit flexibility in the shape of the sine wave.