# How to find the Radius of Curvature of a 3d Helical Sinusoidal Function

Tags: trigonometry, python

I am creating a 3d Helical Sinusoidal Function as found here: [Set of Equations to Helically Wrap a Sine Curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691158/set-of-equations-to-helically-wrap-a-sine-curve)

However, my typical method for finding radius of curvature does not work (as intended) because it 'sees' a tiny radius, assumingly because I am not 'unmapping' the sine curve from it's cylindrical projection, giving very tight radii at the peaks of the sine curve. See image below for example.

[image]
For reference, I am calculating a radius of curvature (min) of ~0.003 units which is way too small... If you look at the 3d plot of the helically wrapped sine wave, it doesn't look as tight.

[image]

Note that both the directly plotted sine curve, $t,f(t)$, and the 3d plot are the same parameters except I reduced the range of $t$ for the 2d plot.

**How would I go about extrapolating this Radius of Curvature equation to find the actual radius of curvature of the sine curve as if it were 'unwrapped' from the cylinder?**

Comment: Possibly... I am wondering why when I calculate the radius of curvature directly for the sine function I get a tiny number of ~0.003 units, but on the 3d plot you can clearly see the minimum radius of curvature of the helically wrapped sine wave is probably on the order of 1 or 2 units.

If you look at the 3d plot then the 2d plot, it is readily seen that the 2d plot has a higher apparent frequency the the cylindrically/helically wrapped wave. So I am assuming there is some conversion I need to do from 3d curve to 2d to preserve the frequency of the wave relative to the cylinder diameter.

Comment: I may have figured it out. Let's say the frequency I use to generate the sine function (helically wrapped) is $f=\frac{d}{2}*\frac{1}{12}$. Then to find the radius of curvature of the normalized 2d curve I would divide the frequency by $\frac{d}{2}$ and end up with $f=\frac{1}{12}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the functions $\overline{f},f : [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ of law:

$$
\overline{f}(t) = a\sin(\overline{\omega}\,t+\phi),
\quad \quad \quad
f(t) = a\sin(\omega\,t+\phi)
$$

and given the curves of parametric equations:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbf{r}_1(t) = \left(t,\;\overline{f}(t),\;0\right); \\
& \mathbf{r}_2(t) = \left(r\cos t + f(t)\sin\theta\sin t,\;r\sin t - f(t)\sin\theta\cos t,\;r\,t\tan\theta + f(t)\cos\theta\,\right); \\
\end{aligned}
$$

the local maximum points are located by:

$$
t^* = \frac{\pi/2+2\,n\,\pi-\phi}{\omega^*},
\quad \quad \quad 
n \in \mathbb{N}\,.
$$

So, all that remains is to impose the equality of the *radii of curvature* at such points:

$$
\rho_1(t^*) = \rho_2(t^*)
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
\frac{||\mathbf{r}_1'(t^*)||^3}{||\mathbf{r}_1'(t^*) \times \mathbf{r}_1''(t^*)||} = \frac{||\mathbf{r}_2'(t^*)||^3}{||\mathbf{r}_2'(t^*) \times \mathbf{r}_2''(t^*)||}
$$

that is, by performing the calculations:

$$
\frac{1}{a\,\overline{\omega}^2} = \frac{a^2\left(1-\cos(4\theta)\right)+8\,r^2}{(2\cos\theta)^2\sqrt{a^2\left(4\,\omega^4+4\,\omega^2+2\right)-2\,a^2\left(2\,\omega^2+1\right)\cos(2\theta)+4\,r^2}}
$$

from which:

$$
\boxed{\overline{\omega} = \frac{2\cos\theta\,\sqrt[4]{a^2\left(4\,\omega^4+4\,\omega^2+2\right)-2\,a^2\left(2\,\omega^2+1\right)\cos(2\theta)+4\,r^2}}{\sqrt{a}\,\sqrt{a^2\left(1-\cos(4\theta)\right)+8\,r^2}}}
$$

or:

$$
\boxed{\omega = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\left(a^2\left(1-\cos(4\theta)\right)+8\,r^2\right)\left(a^2\,\overline{\omega}^4\left(a^2\left(1-\cos(4\theta)\right)+8\,r^2\right)-8\,(\cos\theta)^4\right)}}{8\,a\,(\cos\theta)^2}-(\sin\theta)^2}}\,.
$$

[image]

*Note*: to perform this comparison in `Mathematica` use `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.

Comment: Again, thank you for the great answer!

Interestingly, the first boxed equation ($\omega = ...$) gives nearly identical results to just taking the cylindrical function omega and dividing by the cylinder radius.

My 'divide by radius' method $\rightarrow \omega=0.5235988$.         Your omega method $\rightarrow \omega=0.521623$.           

Coincidence, or are they equivalent and slight difference is due to numerical error in your longer equation?

Comment: Ah I see, thank you again!